# Can’t extract a rar with password?

Tags: python

I need to extract a rarfile but i can't. I've tried `patool` but i think it can't take a password. Then I used `rarfile` but I get this error:

`rarfile.RarCannotExec: Unrar not installed? (rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL='unrar')`

I've downloaded unrar also.
Is there any way?

Comment: Can you please include more details, such as images of what the programs are doing or pasting console output into the question if you're using a terminal-based software? The information that you have currently provided is not sufficient for us to help you yet, especially since we don't know what operating system you're using even.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and Thonny. I'v downloaded the packages from Thonny

Comment: you should try to install "unrar" and **put it in the path**. The error seems very clear to me

Comment: probably the system path (similar to [How do I set system environment variables in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10))

Comment: Yes but i mean what do i need to put in the path? The folder of unrar?

Comment: The full path to the extraction program you want to run, `rarfile`, `unrar`, etc., so append to the path something like: `C:\Program Files (x86)\UnRar`

Comment: Fixed using what you said, Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

`patool` can handle password protected archives. You only need to add verbosity argument to 1 as shown:

```
import patoolib
patoolib.extract_archive(r'your file path', outdir=r"folder path", verbosity=1)
```

now, cmd opened in new window like this and asked you to enter the password:

[image]

if you have other files in it, it asked you again. you can press 'A' to apply this to all files in it like this:

[image]

---

If you want to use `unrar` libray (I don't recommend it  because `patool` is simpler and more comprehensive library), you should download UnRAR.dll from Extras tab in [Rarlab](https://www.rarlab.com).Then install it and add it to environment variables like this:

[image]

and then click on environment variables:
[image]

and then click on new:

[image]

and then complete it as:

Variable name:  UNRAR_LIB_PATH
Variable value: C:\Program Files(x86)\UnrarDLL\x64\UnRAR64.dll

if your windows is 32-bit complete it as:
Variable name:  UNRAR_LIB_PATH
Variable value: C:\Program Files (x86)\UnrarDLL\UnRAR.lib

[image]

I hope this help you.